QGIS server on Azure virtual machine
Im trying to get QGIS Server running on an Azure VM.  I have followed these steps more than once in great detail:
https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/server_manual/getting_started.html#installation-on-windows
Ive looked for tips in Stack Exchange, including this that wasnt applicable.
https://anitagraser.com/2012/04/06/qgis-server-on-windows7-step-by-step/
My httpd.conf looks like this at what I think is the critical bit:

and it all seems to start up ok.  But when I try the following command in the Remote Desktop Browser on the server:
http://localhost:8080/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities
I get no connection:

I have tried to listen to the public IP for the server (now commented out) and that wouldnt start.
Any tips any one please?
Richies

https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/tunnelbiz.qgis?tab=overview states h'ttp://ip/qgisserver?MAP=/MAP=/opt/qgis/projects/world.qgs&LAYERS=countries&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&CRS=EPSG:4326&WIDTH=800&HEIGHT=500&BBOX=-90,-180,90,180' ip=external public ip
